# Pushing custom field data to an array within a plugin

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function

Good Morning

I not very proficient in PHP, on a plugin I am using for car listings there is 'car data' which is filled in while adding a car, I want to add a new option and entry field. I have used a separate plugin to add a custom field to the vehicle listing post type, the problem is outputting the value to the post page.

Within the car listing plugin I found the below php file
https://github.com/barrykooij/wp-car-manager/blob/master/src/Vehicle/Data.php

I added another entry to the array directly and it displayed in the place I want, the questions I have are;

Can I write a function in functions.php to append something to this array?

How would I specify for the values used to be that of my custom field?

Maybe I am barking completely up the wrong tree here but some advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: put your code here which you have tried.

Comment: So I added, the below to the array directly to begin testing, it goes to where I want but returns the front end of: Co2_emissions NOT OVERRIDDEN( co2_emissions )  

`'co2_emissions'        => array(
    'type'        => 'text',
    'label'       => __( 'co2_emissions', 'wp-car-manager' ),
    'key'         => 'co2_emissions',
    'required'    => false,
    'placeholder' => __( 'e.g.', 'wp-car-manager' ) . ' ' . __( '170', 'wp-car-manager' )
   )`